# Joomla template - languages displayed make it white screen no errors

Tags: php, joomla3.0

Sorry for the bad title, but I'm not sure how to describe this in a one-liner...

I'm building a component for Joomla (3.9.19), and in a form I have a select of languages, with the options written in both English and their respective characters.  When I try to display the page of my view, I get the Joomla "white screen of death".  I tracked down the issue to the selections by removing a bunch of them at a time, till the page finally worked.  I then turned on error reporting to maximum, but it has no effect, returning nothing. I checked the apache error log, and nothing related to this is generated.

In the index file of Joomla I added:

```
ini_set('display_errors',true);
error_reporting( E_ALL );
```

But still no errors displayed.

I changed Joomla templates to the defaults Protostar and Beez3 and the page works in both, but doesn't correctly display the international languages.  I copy/pasted the HTML and header meta from another page with the Joomla template I want to use into a normal HTML file, and it works fine - correctly displaying the languages.

I feel like this is related to meta encoding of UTF-8, and if I remove it from my HTML file the characters don't display correctly...but it's in the header, so I don't know why it wouldn't work in Joomla.

I'm lost as to what else I should look for; any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  My IDE (NetBeans 12.0) wasn't correctly setting the file encoding to UTF-8.  I used Notepad++ to convert it, and now my Joomla component is working.